# Using JavaScript to display Laravel's Variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my code I am using [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). I use Laravel 5 and I need to replace the `var states` with my `{{ $jobs }}` variable. I need to list all Job Titles as an array.

In my controller I have

```
$jobs = Job::all(['job_title']);
```

I know the loop method in javascript but I dont know how to "link" my blade's variable in the javascript. Anyone knows how to?

I have tried, in my.js

```
var jobs = {{ $jobs }}
```

But that wont work.

Comment: My question was asked first (7yrs + 1 month ago). The other was was only 7 years ago. How comes mine was closed?

Comment: The duplicate has more votes (both for the question and the answers). Age is not the only factor for the direction of a close vote.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For more complex variable types like arrays your best bet is to convert it into JSON, echo that in your template and decode it in JavaScript. Like this:

```
var jobs = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($jobs) }}");
```

---

Note that PHP has to run over this code to make it work. In this case you'd have to put it inside your Blade template. If you have your JavaScript code in one or more separate files (which is good!) you can just add an inline script tag to your template where you pass your variables. (Just make sure that it runs *before* the rest of your JavaScript code. Usually `document.ready` is the answer to that)

```
<script>
    var jobs = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($jobs) }}");
</script>
```

If you don't like the idea of doing it like this I suggest you fetch the data in a separate ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for that but I got this in the console: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: Can you take a look at the source code of the page and see what's actually passed to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: It points to `var jobs = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($jobs) }}")`

Comment: But this is inside a blade template isn't it?

Comment: No. I have created a .js file and put the code there.

Comment: Well that is obviously not gonna work. If you want to pass PHP variables to JavaScript you have to do it where PHP actually runs.

Comment: So I have to put the js in my page.blade.php?

Comment: Yes. you know PHP and JavaScript can't really talk to each other. What we're doing here is actually just generating JavaScript code (the variable definition) with PHP and echoing the variable out. So you have to do it somewhere PHP runs. And in a separate JS file that's not the case. I hope I explained that well ;)

Comment: Ok let me make few changes. Thanks.

Comment: @lukasgeiter can you not simply `var jobs = {!! json_encode($jobs); !!}; `?

Comment: If some string inside the array $jobs has characters this solution won't work.

Comment: This is a very good explanation and very helpful for people who are confused  why there is an syntax error when they have the variable is accessed in a separate JS file. Also     var jobs = {!! json_encode($jobs); !!};    works.

Answer (score 33):

This works for me

```
jobs = {!! json_encode($jobs) !!};
```

**Notice**

Only use this method if you can guarantee that `$jobs` contains no user input values. Using `{!! ... !!}` outputs values without escaping them which could lead to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Assuming that $jobs is not client controlled and is safe from all kind of injections.

Comment: This works, but it concerns me, since I DO have user input values in my $jobs value. Can you edit the answer to include what to do if you have user input?

Comment: did the job for me. Thanks for this. Noted on the XSS attacks notice.

Answer (score 18):

in **laravel 6** this works for me

using laravel blade directive

```
var jobs = {!! json_encode($jobs) !!};
```

also used `@json` directive

```
var jobs = @json($jobs);
```

using php style

```
 var jobs = <?php echo json_encode($jobs); ?>
```

Comment: This solution worked for Laravel 8 as well

Comment: hi @jignesh can u help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/75150981/14913109

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to above :

`var jobs = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($jobs) }}");`

will return escaped html entities  ,hence you will not be able to loop over the json object in javascript , to solve this please use below :

`var jobs = JSON.parse("{!! json_encode($jobs) !!}");`

or

`var jobs = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($jobs); ?>);`

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 7 I just do

```
var jobs = '{{ $jobs }}';
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is by using the new `@json()` directive of Blade.

**✓ Tested on Laravel 7.x**

```
<script>
    let myVariable = @json($myVariable)
    console.log(myVariable)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

this approach work for me:

```
var job = {!! json_encode($jobs ) !!}
```

and use in java script

Answer (score 1):

In the newer laravel versions, in json `"`(double quotes) gets encoded into `htmlentity` as `&quote;` and unwanted `JSON.parse()` call by using this,

```js
var jobs = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($jobs) }}");
```

and you'll end up with the javascript error. Alternatively, you can use

```js
var jobs = {!! json_encode($jobs, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) !!};
```

As we know, `{!!  !!}` is meant for printing HTML and it will work like a charm. This will reduce the overhead of parsing JSON at the browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by placing a reference on the `window` Object in the `<head>` of my layout file, and then picking that reference up with a mixin that can be injected into any component.

> TLDR SOLUTION

**.env**

```
GEODATA_URL="https://geo.some-domain.com"
```

**config/geodata.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'url' => env('GEODATA_URL')
];
```

**resources/views/layouts/root.blade.php**

```
<head>
    <script>
        window.geodataUrl = "{{ config('geodata.url') }}";
    </script>
</head>
```

**resources/js/components/mixins/geodataUrl.js**

```
const geodataUrl = {
    data() {
        return {
            geodataUrl: window.geodataUrl,
        };
    },
};

export default geodataUrl;
```

**usage**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a :href="geodataUrl">YOLO</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import geodataUrl from '../mixins/geodataUrl';

export default {
    name: 'v-foo',

    mixins: [geodataUrl],

    data() {
        return {};
    },

    computed: {},

    methods: {},
};
</script>
```

> END TLDR SOLUTION

If you want, you can use a global mixin instead by adding this to your `app.js` entrypoint:

```
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
        return {
            geodataUrl: window.geodataUrl,
        };
    },
});
```

I would not recommend using this pattern, however, for any sensitive data because it is sitting on the `window` Object.

I like this solution because it doesn't use any extra libraries, and the chain of code is very clear. It passes the grep test, in that you can search your code for `"window.geodataUrl"` and see everything you need to understand how and why the code is working.

That consideration is important if the code may live for a long time and another developer may come across it.

However, `JavaScript::put([])` is in my opinion, a decent utility that can be worth having, but in the past I have disliked how it can be extremely difficult to debug if a problem happens, because you cannot see where in the codebase the data comes from.

Imagine you have some Vue code that is consuming `window.chartData` that came from `JavaScript::put([ 'chartData' => $user->chartStuff ])`. Depending on the number of references to `chartData` in your code base, it could take you a very long time to discover which PHP file was responsible for making `window.chartData` work, especially if you didn't write that code and the next person has no idea `JavaScript::put()` is being used.

In that case, I recommend putting a comment in the code like:

```
/* data comes from poop.php via JavaScript::put */
```

Then the person can search the code for `"JavaScript::put"` and quickly find it. Keep in mind "the person" could be yourself in 6 months after you forget the implementation details.

It is always a good idea to use Vue component prop declarations like this:

```
props: {
    chartData: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
},
```

My point is, if you use `JavaScript::put()`, then Vue cannot detect as easily if the component fails to receive the data. Vue must assume the data is there on the window Object at the moment in time it refers to it. Your best bet may be to instead create a GET endpoint and make a fetch call in your created/mounted lifecycle method.

I think it is important to have an explicit contract between Laravel and Vue when it comes to getting/setting data.

In the interest of helping you as much as possible by giving you options, here is an example of making a fetch call using ES6 syntax sugar:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/charts/{user}/coolchart', 'UserController@getChart')->name('user.chart');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php**

```
public function getChart(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // do stuff
    $data = $user->chart;

    return response()->json([
        'chartData' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Anywhere in Vue, especially a created lifecycle method:

```
created() {
    this.handleGetChart();
},

methods: {
    async handleGetChart() {
        try {
            this.state = LOADING;
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/charts/${this.user.id}/coolchart`);

            if (typeof data !== 'object') {
                throw new Error(`Unexpected server response. Expected object, got: ${data}`);
            }

            this.chartData = data.chartData;
            this.state = DATA_LOADED;
        } catch (err) {
            this.state = DATA_FAILED;
            throw new Error(`Problem getting chart data: ${err}`);
        }
    },
},
```

That example assumes your Vue component is a Mealy finite state machine, whereby the component can only be in one state at any given time, but it can freely switch between states.

I'd recommend using such states as computed props:

```
computed: {
    isLoading() { return (this.state === LOADING); },
    isDataLoaded() { return (this.state === DATA_LOADED); },
    isDataFailed() { return (this.state === DATA_FAILED); },
},
```

With markup such as:

```
<div v-show="isLoading">Loading...</div>
<v-baller-chart v-if="isDataLoaded" :data="chartData"></v-baller-chart>
<button v-show="isDataFailed" type="button" @click="handleGetChart">TRY AGAIN</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8. You can use blade template por this...

```
const jobs = @json($jobs ?? NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var job_id = '{{ $jobs->first()->id}}';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: This will cause problems if the value has single quotes in it