# How to pass data from Laravel View to Ajax or Javascript code without html div (id or class) - Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

So, currently I am passing values stored in Database MySQL to **View** (using Controller). I do simple querying `ModelName::where()->first();`.

I have my data right now in **View**. I want to use that data in **Ajax or Javascript** code that I am writing.

I can have 46 values and one way to do this is to have `<div id="field1"></div>` for 46 times set div style to `display:none` in css and in Javascript use `document.getElementById('field1');` to access the values and finally, do whatever I want to do with it.

But I find this quite long and un-necessary to do as there is no point of printing all the values in html first and then accessing it. How can I directly get `{{$data}}` in Javascript?

**myCode**

```
public function index(Request $request){

        $cattfs = Cattf::all();
        $cattts = Cattt::all();
        $cattos = Catto::all();

        return view('/index',compact('cattfs'));
}
```

**View**

Nothing in the view. and I prefer it to be none.

**Javascript and Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    init(); 
});

function init(){
    my_Date = new Date();
    var feedback = $.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
    }).success(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  //I have some data called data from url
  //I want some data from controller like: cattf,cattt,catto
  //I will combine url data and cattf and do simple arithmetic to it
  //finally output to the view.
  }).responseText;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to append elements after an ajax call or in the initial view setup? You may need to use a for loop in javascript. Get all the elements with classes and for loop them. While looping, set each one to `.show()`

Comment: @senty I don't seem to understand your question, can you rephrase it? If you mean appending html elements then no.

Comment: @senty Can you show what you mean? I get the part of using while loop so no repetition but then I dont want any {{$fields}} in html as there is no role those values in html View.

Comment: `@foreach ($data) your html @endfoeach` is what you need to do in the blade html. Assign them classes. Then depending on how you want to show them, you can do it in javascript

Comment: Ahhh.. I see what you mean. Let me check that

Comment: @senty  I have added some code. have a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308441/4705339

Comment: @senty  I get this error when I follow the link: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ajax.js:16)
    at n (jquery.js:768)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:832)
    at w (jquery.js:3799)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.js:4083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way would be to actually make a small API to get your data. Let's say you wanted to retrieve users.

In the `api.php` file in your route folder:

```
Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return Post::all();
});
```

and then you just need to use `http://yourUrl.dev/api/posts` as your URL sent in your `.ajax()` call to work with what you need.

Comment: Thanks will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I found best solution use this: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

It takes values from controller directly to Javascript.