# VueJS Form Input Binding

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Hey so I'm a beginnerin Vue and I only encountered this problem when I used the foreach loop
Issue: Whenever I select any checkbox all get selected.

create.blade.php

```
  @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
              <li class="list-group-item bold">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="{{$permission->id}}"
                  :custom-value="{{$permission->id}}" v-model="permissionsSelected">
                  <label for="{{$permission->id}}">{{$permission->display_name}}
                  <em>{{$permission->description}}</em></label>
              </li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions" :value="permissionsSelected">



<script>
 var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     permissionsSelected: ''
   }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: all checkboxes have same model `v-model="permissionsSelected"` that's why they all change together

Comment: Yes, that's how it's written in the docs as well: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: `permissionsSelected` should be an array, as written in the docs.

Comment: in your case it's a string, so change it to`permissionsSelected: []`

Comment: also, you are missing `value=""` attribute on  `<input >`

Comment: I would recommend you to look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308441/using-javascript-to-display-laravels-variable), to pass permissions into var permission = ..., and to use that with vue, so you don't have blade foreach mix with vue

Comment: also in laravel blade, if you want to use vue templating, you need to look into [this docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks)

Comment: @ljubadr worked when I changed :custom-value to value do you know what's the difference between them exactly? also yea I changed permissionsSelected into an array

Comment: You can add this `<span>Checked permissions: @{{ permissionsSelected }}</span>` before you close the `<div id="app">` to see the difference

Comment: Also take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems seems to be that `<input>` was missing `:value=".."`. Also permissionsSelected should be an array: `permissionsSelected: []`

I would recommend you not to mix laravel blade `@foreach` with vue.

Instead pass `$permissions` to javascript and render the list with vue. You can look how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308441/using-javascript-to-display-laravels-variable)

One more thing, from laravel documentation

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a
>   given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @
>   symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should
>   remain untouched

And here is your updated example

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="list-group-item bold" v-for="permission in permissions">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        :id="permission.id"
        :value="permission.id"
        v-model="permissionsSelected"
      >
      <label :for="permission.id">@{{ permission.display_name }}
        <em>@{{ permission.description }}</em>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="permissions" :value="permissionsSelected">
</div>

<script>
  var permissions = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($permissions) }}");

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      permissions: permissions,
      permissionsSelected: [],
    }
  });
</script>
```