# Laravel - Use blade in Jquery with Ajax to get data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to build a "view details" page for many "request" in database, with a customised progress bar, which can be access by calling `RequestListController@show`. I store progress for each "request" in MySQL. I want to get the progress of a request based on the id with Ajax so that I can use Jquery to update the progress bar each time the user open a "view details" page. But this doesn't work, I use `alert()` to test if it works, and nothing will happen. If I remove the `{{ $catRequest-id }}`, I can get a alert. Does it mean I cannot use blade in the url in javascript? If so, is there a better way to get data in the database?

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax-get-progress/{{ $catRequest->id }}",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response["progress"]);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

```php
Route::get('/ajax-get-progress/{$catRequest->id}', 'AjaxController@getProgress'); // ajax gets progress by id

Route::get('/request-list/show/requestID/{requestID}', 'RequestListController@show');

public function getProgress($requestID)
{
    $progress = CatRequest::where('id', $requestID)->first();
    $userData['progress'] = $progress;
    echo json_encode($userData);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If the script is in the blade file then you can use it

Comment: I think the best way to do that, it's to use Promise, with updating your progress after each request

Comment: @KhaldounNd The script is in the .blade.php table, but it shows no response with the parameter `requestID`, once I remove it, it can work. Am I using it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions on stackoverflow. That should do the trick:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58179530/7807619

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/ajax-get-progress/{requestID}', 'AjaxController@getProgress'); // ajax gets progress by id
```

```
public function getProgress($requestID)
    {
        $progress = CatRequest::where('id', 1)->first()->progress;
        $userData['progress'] = $requestID;
        echo json_encode($userData);
        exit;
    }
```

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                        url: "/ajax-get-progress/{{ $catRequest->id }}",
                        type: "get",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response) {
                            alert(response['progress']);
                        }
                    });
        });
    </script>
```