# Send Request In Laravel Using AJAX GET Method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Want to Access Show function data through AJAX, but it returns error when i passed id variable in route

**Contoller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $features['UnitFeatures'] = UnitFeatures::find($id);
    return $features;
}
```

**View Blade File**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

var feature_id = $('#unitFeatures').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('unitfeatures.show',feature_id) }}', // error in this line when i pass feature_id value to route
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
     }
    });
  });
```

Please give me a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308441/using-javascript-to-display-laravels-variable

Comment: No, i get a id from a input value and pass in route

Comment: Maybe this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript

Comment: Try passing id in array with key value pair, Something like this `route('unitfeatures.show', ['id' => feature_id])`

Comment: @LQS that will not work because you cannot insert a JS variable into PHP code

Comment: @Aless55, yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that you cannot access a JS variable in your `{{}}` PHP code.
You will have to get the route uri and replace the placeholder manually in your JS code.

You can get the URI of your Route with this piece of code:
`\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('unitfeatures.show ')->uri`

This returns the uri as a string like that: `/sometext/{id}`

Now you can simply replace the **{id}** with the **feature_id**  by using `str.replace()` or whatever function you like.

```
var feature_id = $('#unitFeatures').val();
var origUrl = '{{ \Route::getRoutes()->getByName('unitfeatures.show ')->uri}}';
$.ajax({
    url: origUrl.replace('{id}', feature_id), 
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
     }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i will use route url also. but the issue is that i use Route::resource('unitfeatures','FeaturesController') so it auto generates SHOW function. That i call unitfeatures.show

Comment: I know the problem. I did not do any research on it, but maybe there is a way so you can access the raw named route.

Comment: @MUSTUFA did it work or did you find another answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem With You are using Javascript Variable in PHP Code You can use Javascript Variable After Execution of PHP Code treated as a String.**

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('unitfeatures.show') }}"+'/'+feature_id,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
     }
    });
  });
```

Comment: this won't work because the `route('unitfeatures.show', $id)` needs the $id to generate the route

Comment: @Aless55 `route('unitfeatures.show', $id)` will generate URL same as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/your_url/id` show you can make it the same way I answered, I have tested its working fine.

Comment: yes, but this `{{ route('unitfeatures.show') }}` will give you an error

Comment: you need to define it in  route file `Route::get('/your_url', 'controller@function')->name('unitfeatures.show');` then `{{ route('unitfeatures.show') }}` will work fine.

Comment: @Aless55 please check the laravel docs for **Generating URLs To Named Routes**

Comment: the route is defined as: `Route::get('/your_url/{id}', 'controller@function')->name('unitfeatures.show');` , so the `$id` is needed for calling the route, you cannot call it without it.

Comment: you can add it manually after generating the route string, concatenate the URL string with id which you are getting in javascript variable like I have done in the above answer.

Comment: it is only possible if your route is defined without the $id parameter, otherwise calling your named route will throw the following error: `Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException : Missing required parameters for [Route:....`

Comment: yes you need to remove `{id}` from your route otherwise it will throw an error.