# Store PhP variable in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm really new into web dev and I'm working on a project which uses the TALL stack:

- *Laravel Mix*;
- *Livewire*;
- *AlpineJS* and;
- *TailwindCSS*.

I want to get a PhP variable and store it in a JavaScript variable, so I can do jQuery/JavaScript stuff with it.

The PhP variable is `<?php Auth::user()->kyc_status ?>` and I would like to store it in a JavaScript variable called `kycStatus`. The idea could be represented by something like `let kycStatus = <?php Auth::user()->kyc_status ?>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your PHP data in a html data attribute  and get it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    let kycStatus = {{ Auth::user()->kyc_status }}
</script>
```

Comment: You probably need to quote it if its a string, `let kycStatus = '{{ Auth::user()->kyc_status }}';`

Comment: I don't think quote is needed, {{ }} represents a variable, you don't put a quote on a variable like `'$variable'`, if the variable is a string type, then kycStatus will get the string type

Comment: The quote is for the JS to know its a string, see where I put the quotes in my comment

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, could you please accept the answer as the right answer, thanks in advance

Comment: For sure, @Jacky.S. I was about to do that! ;)
Could you please explain me the difference on doing {!! json_encode(Auth::user()->kyc_status) !!}; and '{{ Auth::user()->kyc_status }}'; ?

Comment: you could refer to this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308441/using-javascript-to-display-laravels-variable

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following

```js
<script>    
    var kycStatus = {!! json_encode(Auth::user()->kyc_status) !!};
</script>
```

Or use this Laravel package https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer to pass some server-side string/array/collection/whatever to your JavaScript.

Comment: There's also a `@json` blade directive, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json

Comment: Yes :thumbs_up _

Comment: This solution also worked. Thanks @JuniorGantin.
What is the difference on doing {!! json_encode(Auth::user()->kyc_status) !!}; and '{{ Auth::user()->kyc_status }}'; ?