# Why is Laravel route parameter not working using jQuery backtick syntax?

Tags: jquery, laravel, backticks

The `${elem.id}` before *read more* section is not working.

### My code

```
var tr = `<div class="course-content">
                      <h3><a href="">${elem.title}</a></h3>
                          <p>${elem.description}</p>
                             <a class="default-btn" href="{{route('course.details',${elem.id})}}">read more</a>
                  </div> 
               </div>
           </div>`;    
                            
  $('#courses').append(tr);
```

Comment: You can't put jQuery variables into PHP functions because, when jQuery is processed, PHP is already processed into HTML.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, so how should I pass this id to the route?

Comment: I did something like this and worked:
`<a class="default-btn" href="courses/${elem.id}">read more</a>`

Comment: Yep, that's okay

Comment: You can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308441/using-javascript-to-display-laravels-variable